# Algorithm simulator (bubble and selection sorts)

Tags: javascript, html, css, simulation, animation

I am concerned where it can be improved.

- Main concerns are coding style.
- Any other improvements are welcome too.
- **Priority is on JavaScript**, review for HTML/CSS are welcome too.

#### What it does:

- Simulate Bubble Sort graphically with animations.
- Simulate Selection Sort graphically with animations.
- <s>There are some visual kinks in Selection Sort simulation but</s> it sorts correctly and works to the best of my knowledge.

#### Information:

- Contains Single HTML Page,Single CSS file and Single JavaScript file
- Prototype.js => v1.7
- script.aculo.us => v1.9.0
- **Screen clipping, just a part of it**

[image]

---

**JavaScript**: base.js

```
/**
 * Bhathiya Perera IT110057-04
 *
 */

/**
 * Draws an array with indexes in box structure
 * @param {Object} arr Array to be drawn
 */
function drawarray(arr) {
    var boxset = $("boxset");
    var boxsetnum = $("boxsetnum");
    boxset.innerHTML = "";
    boxsetnum.innerHTML = "";

    boxset.hide();
    boxsetnum.hide();

    var boxsetStr = "";
    var boxsetnumStr = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boxsetStr = boxsetStr + "<div class=box id='arrbox" + i.toString() + "' >" + arr[i] + "<\/div>"
        boxsetnumStr = boxsetnumStr + "<div class=box2>" + (i + 1) + "<\/div>"
    }

    boxset.innerHTML = boxsetStr;
    boxsetnum.innerHTML = boxsetnumStr;

    boxset.show();
    boxsetnum.show();

}

/**
 * Simulate Bubble Sort (Ascending only)
 * @param {Object} a Array (Must be an integer array)
 */
function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
                    x : 32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + (i + 1).toString(), {
                    x : -32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
                    x : 0,
                    y : 32,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + (i + 1).toString(), {
                    x : 0,
                    y : -32,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
                    x : -32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + (i + 1).toString(), {
                    x : 32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                var temp = a[i];
                var t1 = document.getElementById("arrbox" + i.toString());
                var t2 = document.getElementById("arrbox" + (i + 1).toString());
                var t3 = t1.id;
                t1.id = t2.id;
                t2.id = t3;
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}

/**
 * This function must be called by the simulate button
 * And this will initialize the array and pass it to  bubbleSort()
 */
function bubble_simulate() {
    var numbers = $("arrayinput").value;
    var toBeSorted = numbers.split(",");
    if (toBeSorted.length >= 1) {
        var toBeSortedi = new Array();
        for (var q = 0; q < toBeSorted.length; q++) {
            toBeSortedi[q] = parseInt(toBeSorted[q]);
        }
        drawarray(toBeSortedi);
        bubbleSort(toBeSortedi);
    }
}
/**
 * Simulate Selection Sort 
 * @param {Object} sortMe array to be sorted
 */
function selectionSort(sortMe) {
    var i, j, small, tmp2;
    //small contains the smallest value
    //tmp2 is used only for swapping
    for ( i = 0; i < sortMe.length; i++) {
        small = i;

        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + small.toString(), {
                    x : 32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
        for ( j = i + 1; j < sortMe.length; j++) {
            if (sortMe[j] < sortMe[small]) {
                //drop the current smallest (its j)
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + small.toString(), {
                    x : -32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
                small = j;
                //raise new smallest (its j)
                new Effect.Move("arrbox" + j.toString(), {
                    x : 32,
                    y : 0,
                    queue : 'end'
                });
            }
        }
        //swapping 
        var l = (small-i)*32; //length difference between the two array elements
        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
            x : -32,
            y : 0,
            queue : 'end'
        }); 
        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
            x : 0,
            y : l,
            queue : 'end'
        });
        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + small.toString(), {
            x : 0,
            y : -l,
            queue : 'end'
        });
        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + small.toString(), {
            x : -32,
            y : 0,
            queue : 'end'
        });     
        new Effect.Move("arrbox" + i.toString(), {
            x : 32,
            y : 0,
            queue : 'end'
        });         
        tmp2 = sortMe[small];
        sortMe[small] = sortMe[i];
        sortMe[i] = tmp2;
        //swap id-s'
        var t1 = document.getElementById("arrbox" + i.toString());
        var t2 = document.getElementById("arrbox" + small.toString());
        var t3 = t1.id;
        t1.id = t2.id;
        t2.id = t3;
    }
}
/**
* Simulate seelction Sort 
* The simulate button will call this
*/
function selection_simulate() {
    var numbers = $("arrayinput").value;
    var toBeSorted = numbers.split(",");
    if (toBeSorted.length >= 1) {
        var toBeSortedi = new Array();
        for (var q = 0; q < toBeSorted.length; q++) {
            toBeSortedi[q] = parseInt(toBeSorted[q]);
        }
        drawarray(toBeSortedi);
        selectionSort(toBeSortedi);
    }
}
function show_selection_sort() {
    var strVar="";
    strVar += "<h2>Selection sort<\/h2>";
    strVar += "A{";
    strVar += "<input type=\"text\" id=\"arrayinput\" style=\"width:550px;\"\/>";
    strVar += "}";
    strVar += "<hr style=\"visibility:hidden;\"\/>";
    strVar += "<div class=\"dbutton\" onclick=\"selection_simulate();\">";
    strVar += "Simulate";
    strVar += "<\/div>";
    strVar += "<hr style=\"visibility:hidden;\"\/>";
    strVar += "<table>";
    strVar += "<tr>";
    strVar += "<td><div id=\"boxsetnum\">";
    strVar += "<\/div><\/td>";
    strVar += "<td><div id=\"boxset\">";
    strVar += "<\/div><\/td>";
    strVar += "<\/tr>";
    strVar += "<\/table> ";
    var simulbox = $("simulbox");
    simulbox.innerHTML = strVar;
    simulbox.highlight({
        startcolor : '#D0E0D0',
        endcolor : '#DDDDDD'
    });

}
function show_bubble_sort() {
    var strVar="";
    strVar += "<h2>Bubble sort<\/h2>";
    strVar += "A{";
    strVar += "<input type=\"text\" id=\"arrayinput\" style=\"width:550px;\"\/>";
    strVar += "}";
    strVar += "<hr style=\"visibility:hidden;\"\/>";
    strVar += "<div class=\"dbutton\" onclick=\"bubble_simulate();\">";
    strVar += "Simulate";
    strVar += "<\/div>";
    strVar += "<hr style=\"visibility:hidden;\"\/>";
    strVar += "<table>";
    strVar += "<tr>";
    strVar += "<td><div id=\"boxsetnum\">";
    strVar += "<\/div><\/td>";
    strVar += "<td><div id=\"boxset\">";
    strVar += "<\/div><\/td>";
    strVar += "<\/tr>";
    strVar += "<\/table> ";

    var simulbox = $("simulbox");
    simulbox.innerHTML = strVar;
    simulbox.highlight({
        startcolor : '#D0E0D0',
        endcolor : '#DDDDDD'
    });

}
```

**HTML**: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script src="javascripts/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/lib/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/algo/base.js" type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
        <title>DAA Algorithm Simulator IT110057-04</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maindiv">
            <h1>Algorithem Simulator</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                This web page was created by Bhathiya Perera for DAA Assignment.
                <br />
                IT110057-04 Perera B.A.B.N.H.
            </p>
            <hr>
            <table style="text-align:center;">
                <tr id="algoselect">
                    <td>
                    <div class="algobox"  onclick="show_bubble_sort();" style="float:left;">
                        <h2>Bubble Sort</h2>
                        <p>
                            Bubble Sort is a simple sorting algorithm that works by repeatedly stepping through the list to be sorted
                        </p>
                    </div></td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="algobox"  onclick="show_selection_sort();" style="float:right;">
                        <h2>Selection Sort</h2>
                        <p>
                            Selection sort is simple a sorting algorithm, specifically an in-place comparison sort.
                        </p>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="simulbox" id="simulbox">
                        <h2>Welcome to Alogorithm Simulator</h2>
                        <p>Please select an algorithm to continue.</p>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**: style.css

```
body {
    background-image: url('./light_bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
h1 {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
}
div#maindiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 670px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-family: Monospace;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: #D0C0D0 1px solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
div.box {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #000000 1px solid;
}
div.box2 {
    width: 32px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
div.simulbox {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: #D0C0D0 1px solid;
}
div.algobox {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 215px;
    height: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: #D0C0D0 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
div.algobox:hover {
    background-color: #E0D0E0;
}
div.algobox:active {
    background-color: #D0C0D0;
}

div.dbutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: #D0C0D0 1px solid;
}
div.dbutton:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0F0;
}
div.dbutton:active {
    background-color: #D0D0E0;
}
```

---

#### Related Links:

- [Repository (gh-pages branch)](https://github.com/JaDogg/SortingSimulator)
- [Live](http://jadogg.github.io/SortingSimulator/)

Comment: You can ignore the strike through part, It works as intended. (Although you might find that it animates weirdly,It's not a bug,It's exactly how the sort happens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am familiar with neither Prototype nor Scriptaculous.

**JS**

- `drawarray()` should be named `drawArray()`.
- You can take advantage of `+=` instead of `boxsetStr = boxsetStr + ...`.
- `/` is not a special character in strings and does not need to be escaped. `"<\/div>"` is clutter; it's harder to read than `"</div>"`.
- You have *a ton* of repetition. In particular, your parameters for `Effect.Move` are repeated. You should store them in a constant.
- When concatenating a variable to a string, it is implicitly converted. You don't need to explicitly call `i.toString()`. Combining this with the previous point, we get:

  ```
  var MOVE_LEFT = { x: -32, y: 0, queue: "end" };
  ...
  new Effect.move("arrbox" + i, MOVE_LEFT);
  ```
- Continuing from the above, it would make more sense to put the swapping animation in a separate callable function.
- In `bubble_simulate()`, you use `parseInt` without explicitly stating the base. In general, you should explicitly state the base with `parseInt(toBeSorted[q], 10)`. This is because in older browsers which do not comply with ECMAScript 5, strings leading with a `0` are treated as octal numbers, so `parseInt("010") => 8`. In practice, this is not the current behaviour of any of the major browsers.
- In `selectionSort`, you declare your loop variables at the top, while in `bubbleSort`, you declared `i` in your loop. This would be fine if you actually reused your loop variables in `selectionSort`, but you don't; the resulting inconsistency strikes me as odd.
- In `show_selection_sort()`, it seems like you would benefit greatly from templating. It certainly looks extremely busy.

**HTML**

- You used `<table>` for layout. No. Bad. `<table>`s are for data, not for layout. (Exception: HTML for email.) You should be using `<div>`s.
- There's some unnecessary whitespace where you included `algo/base.js`. There's some more after `</table>` and `</body>`. I say unnecessary because these do not make your structure any easier to read.
- For some reason you have `style` attributes on things where some improved CSS could easily apply.

**CSS**

- You're using `cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;`. This is no longer necessary; the last browser to support `cursor: hand` but not `cursor: pointer` was IE 5.5, which was dropped from support almost ten years ago.
- Vendor prefixes for `border-radius` have not been required for quite a while. [This article on *css-tricks.com*](http://css-tricks.com/do-we-need-box-shadow-prefixes/) estimates less than 1% of 2012 traffic to support prefixed versions but not the bare version.
- In general, people like their CSS to be ordered in some fashion, whether grouped by category or alphabetically. I can't seem to detect an ordering for your CSS. (Of all the points made, this one matters the least.)